# Docker - docker-compose 'version' doesn't have any configuration options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I am newbie in the Docker world, I spent my holiday to learn this docker (however it is much harder than Vagrant).
So I use Ubuntu 16.04, I installed successfully the docker and docker-compose.

I read this tutorial: [Quickstart: Docker Compose and Rail](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/)s
But this is not working... maybe the tutorial is not fine.

I have this docker-compose.yml:

```
db:
    image: postgres
web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
       - .:/www/html
    ports:
       - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
       - db
```

I got this error always:

```
$ docker-compose run web rails new . --force --database=postgresql --skip-bundle
ERROR: Validation failed in file './docker-compose.yml', reason(s):
Unsupported config option for 'web' service: 'depends_on'
```

Mmmm, okay, I read a lot of google result, and it seems I am in a troube, because I use Ubuntu. Unfortunately the highest version number of docker in Ubuntu it is only 1.5.2. (I tried download the 1.7.1 with curl, but 1.5.2 installed automatically.)

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.11.1
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   5604cbe
 Built:        Tue Apr 26 23:43:49 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.11.1
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   5604cbe
 Built:        Tue Apr 26 23:43:49 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Do you have any ideas, how can I run the rails based docker?
I cannot install the docker machine, because I use ubuntu and the installation always will be failed.

However my PHP docker-compose.yml is fine, because I can run it :slight_smile: But this rails tutorial is not good.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is you removed the two first lines of the example tutorial your are following, and they do matter.
Because, looking at the `docker` version you do have you should be on a version of `docker-compose` higher than 1.6.x.

To identify this, you can run

```
$ docker-compose -v
```

In my case that gets me

> docker-compose version 1.7.0, build 0d7bf73

If your version there is 1.7.x or higher then the information below definitely apply to you.

This should be working:

```
version: '2'   ## <- this line matter and you removed it out the tutorial
services:      ## <- this line also
    db:
        image: postgres
    web:
        build: .
        command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
        volumes:
            - .:/www/html
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        depends_on:
            - db
```

> There are currently three versions of the Compose file format:
>
> 1. Version 1, the legacy format. This is specified by omitting a version
>    key at the root of the YAML.
> 2. Version 2.x. This is specified with a version: '2' or version: '2.1'
>    entry at the root of the YAML.
> 3. Version 3.x, the latest and recommended version, designed to be
>    cross-compatible between Compose and the Docker Engine’s swarm mode.
>    This is specified with a version: '3' or version: '3.1', etc., entry
>    at the root of the YAML.

Additionally, here is a little `docker-compose`version / Composer file matrix:

| Compose file format | Docker Engine release |
| --- | --- |
| 3.8 | 19.03.0+ |
| 3.7 | 18.06.0+ |
| 3.6 | 18.02.0+ |
| 3.5 | 17.12.0+ |
| 3.4 | 17.09.0+ |
| 3.3 | 17.06.0+ |
| 3.2 | 17.04.0+ |
| 3.1 | 1.13.1+ |
| 3.0 | 1.13.0+ |
| 2.4 | 17.12.0+ |
| 2.3 | 17.06.0+ |
| 2.2 | 1.13.0+ |
| 2.1 | 1.12.0+ |
| 2.0 | 1.10.0+ |
| 1.0 | 1.9.1.+ |

<sup>*Source: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#compatibility-matrix*</sup>

> - Version 1 is supported by Compose up to 1.6.x. It will be deprecated in a future Compose release.
> - Version 2 files are supported by Compose 1.6.0+ and require a Docker Engine of version 1.10.0+.
> - An upgrade of version 2 that introduces new parameters only available with Docker Engine version 1.12.0+
> - An upgrade of version 2.1 that introduces new parameters only available with Docker Engine version 1.13.0+. This version also allows to specify default scale numbers inside the service’s configuration.
> - Designed to be cross-compatible between Compose and the Docker Engine’s swarm mode, version 3 removes several options and adds several more.

On docker documentation pages there are also now practical guides on how to upgrade your Compose file:

- [One to upgrade from 1 to 2.x](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-1-to-2x)
- [One to upgrade from 2.x to 3.x](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-2x-to-3x)

Additional useful docker Compose documentation:

- [List of all docker-compose
  versions](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/)
- [Compose file version
  1](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v1/)
- [Compose file version
  2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/)
- [Compose file version
  3 (current)](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)

Answer (score 4):

This shows that the version of your docker-compose is of a lesser version. So, if you are on Ubuntu, you can uninstall docker-compose:

```
sudo apt-get purge docker-compose
```

Then, you can re-install the latest version with these command:

```
curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.10.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Then,

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Comment: This answer solved my problem. I had to run all three commands as `sudo`, and also had to change the install directory to `/usr/bin/` to make Nextcloud install properly

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [@b.enoit.be answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37124632/2013580):

**Ubuntu** (and probably **Debian**) users:

**Do not use apt `docker-compose` package!**

If you are using it right now:

```
apt purge docker-compose
```

It works just fine with their [official instructions](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/):

```
curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.10.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose;
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose;
docker-compose --version; // docker-compose version 1.10.0, build 4bd6f1a
```

You might want to install their official [docker-engine](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntu/) too first, if you also used apt packages for this.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer from b.enoit.be is the right one but just for completeness (and for the sake of anyone using an old version of docker-compose who can't update just yet) it should be possible to make this work by changing `depends_on` to `links`:

```
db:
    image: postgres
web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
       - .:/www/html
    ports:
       - "3000:3000"
    links:
       - db
```

This is because `depends_on` has only been added in the new version of the docker-compose format.