# CircleCI './docker-compose.yml' service 'version' doesn't have any configuration options

Tags: docker, docker-compose, circleci

Related, *but not duplicated*: [Docker - docker-compose 'version' doesn't have any configuration options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37121784/docker-docker-compose-version-doesnt-have-any-configuration-options)

I am currently using a **v2** `docker-compose.yml` with the following `circle.yml`:

```
machine:
  services:
    - docker

test:
  post:
    - docker build --rm=false -t zurfyx/repo:$CIRCLE_SHA1 .
    - docker-compose run web npm test

deployment:
  hub:
    branch: master
    commands:
      - docker login -e $DOCKER_EMAIL -u $DOCKER_USER -p $DOCKER_PASS
      - docker push zurfyx/repo:$CIRCLE_SHA1
```

CircleCI gives the following output:

```
docker-compose run web npm test
ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml' service 'version' doesn't have any configuration options. All top level keys in your docker-compose.yml must map to a dictionary of configuration options.

docker-compose run web npm test returned exit code 1
```

I tried the [following solutions](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/docker-compose-version-change/9685/) that show up on a very recent CircleCI forum post, but I didn't manage to get rid of the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Upgrading **both** docker and docker-compose to the latest version is required:

```
machine:
  pre:
    - curl -sSL https://s3.amazonaws.com/circle-downloads/install-circleci-docker.sh | bash -s -- 1.10.0
    - pip install --upgrade pip
    - pip install docker-compose

  services:
    - docker
```

**Why both?**

Some say that upgrading docker-compose to the latest version by using pip is enough, but apparently is not (because the current Docker Engine CircleCI version does not support it, at least not anymore):

> ERROR: The Docker Engine version is less than the minimum required by
>   Compose. Your current project requires a Docker Engine of version
>   1.10.0 or greater.

If you just upgrade Docker engine, it does not make any difference, since a higher docker-compose version is required to parse v2 YAML documents.